# Continue bat script execution after >

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a `.bat` file that is as below:

```
1. @echo off
2. cd C:\flyway
3. flyway info > C:\db-update\version.txt 
4. setlocal
5. cd C:\db-update\ 
6. findstr /I "Schema version: 1." C:\db-update\version.txt > C:\db-update\version1.txt 
7. set /p texte=< C:\db-update\version1.txt 
8. echo %texte% 
9. endlocal
```

As soon as it executes line 3, my script execution is stopping and from line `4`, it is not getting executed. How can I bring back the cursor to line `4` and keep executing my script?

Comment: Is the 'flyway' command actually `flyway.exe` or is it `flyway.bat`? Go to C:\flyway and check.

Comment: I guess you can shorten that to a single line: `@for /f "delims=" %%a in ('flyway^|findstr /lic:"Schema version: 1."') do @echo %%a`

Comment: @Stephan, can you please be more specific?

Comment: What do you mean with "more specific"? Execute `flyway`, filter for the relevant line, and extract the desired number with a `for` loop. No need to `cd` to the folder, no need for a temporary file. Oh - sorry, it should be `... in ('C:\flyway\flyway info^|findstr ...` of course.